# scrapy being possibly blocked by site

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I've been trying to scrape text off of this site http://www.ewtn.com/daily-readings/?date=2017-11-26

when I type from the shell

```
>response.xpath('//text()').extract()
```

I am having trouble accessing the following html info

```
<span id="cur-date">Sunday, November 26, 2017</span>
```

which would be **Sunday, November 26, 2017**

```
<div class="reading-type">First Reading</div>
```

which would be **First Reading**

I do get almost everything else on the page though - it seems like scrapy is being blocked

Comment: JavaScript. Scrapy doesn't run JavaScript. Try to open the page with a browser which blocks JS, and you'll see the problem.

Comment: thanks! solved it with scrapy-webdriver

Answer (score 1):

Thanks goes to Markus for putting me in the right direction! I used [scrapy-webdriver](https://github.com/brandicted/scrapy-webdriver) to let me render JavaScript in PhantomJS in order to parse it with Scrapy... since Scrapy does not run JavaScript and this site seems to be injecting it directly into the browser to be converted into HTML... PhantomJS is a headless browser that does the JavaScript running for Scrapy.